# Xml Sequence deserialization with RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I have this xml feed from an API with a XML sequence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Function>
    <Cmd>2002</Cmd>
    <Status>1</Status>
    <Cmd>2003</Cmd>
    <Status>0</Status>
    <Cmd>2004</Cmd>
    <Status>0</Status>
    <Cmd>1012</Cmd>
    <Status>3</Status>
    <Cmd>2006</Cmd>
    <Status>0</Status>
    <Cmd>2007</Cmd>
    <Status>0</Status>
    ...
</Function>
```

I already tried a few options for deserialization with Restsharp. Ideally I would like to have something like the following, but it's obviously not working.

```
public class MyResponse
{
    public List<Setting> Settings { get; set;}
}

public class Setting
{
    public int Cmd { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You have one more `Cmd` than `Status` in your XML.  I assume that's a typo in your question?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DotNetXmlDeserializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/DotNetXmlDeserializer.cs) of RestSharp to make Microsoft's [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do the actual deserialization.  Define your `MyResponse` class as follows, using [XML serialization attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify element names and also special handling for the `Cmd/Status` alternating sequence of elements:

```
[XmlRoot("Function")]
public class MyResponse
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Setting> Settings { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Proxy property to convert Settings to an alternating sequence of Cmd / Status elements.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XElement[] Elements 
    {
        get
        {
            if (Settings == null)
                return null;
            return Settings.SelectMany(s => new[] { new XElement("Cmd", s.Cmd), new XElement("Status", s.Status) }).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                Settings = null;
            else
                Settings = value.Where(e => e.Name == "Cmd").Zip(value.Where(e => e.Name == "Status"), (cmd, status) => new Setting { Cmd = (int)cmd, Status = (int)status }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
        var serializer = new DotNetXmlDeserializer();
        var myResponse = serializer.Deserialize<MyResponse>(response);
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ke4GUu).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't match your object model. 
There are two simple ways of fixing it
 * Make your XML response actually contain a list structure
 * Write a custom parser. 
 ** https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Who is responsible for generating the XML / Soap? Looks like something hand crafted.

Look at the examples on the Restsharp page regarding the deserialisation of a list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NestedListSample>
    <images>
        <image src="1.gif">value1</image>
        <image src="2.gif">value2</image>
        <image src="3.gif">value3</image>
        <image src="4.gif">value4</image>
    </images>
</NestedListSample>
```

Will map to the following C# schema:

```
public class ListSample
{
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Src { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have no power over the xml feed: it is as it is. I would avoid a custom parser if RestSharp has a way to support this structure.

Comment: By the way the RestSharp documentation covers only InlineLists and NestedLists. I see no mention of sequences.