# C# List of items serialize to XML: how to remove wrapping list tag instead off the wrapper tag of the items in the list

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I need to serialice an object to XML. I'm stuck on this property, which is a list of objects, where I need the wrapper tag of the list, but not the wrapper tag of the items in the list.

My code:

```
public class Partner
{
   //[XmlElement("PartnerContact")] //This will remove the wrapper tag, not the item tags whitin the list tag
   public List<PartnerContact> PartnerContacts { get; set; } = new List<PartnerContact> { };
}

public class PartnerContact
{
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

What I have (whitout using the XmlElement attribute):

```
  <Partner> 
     <PartnerContacts>
        <PartnerContact>
          <ContactType>AR</ContactType>
          <Name>John Doe</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>0123456789</PhoneNumber>
          <EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
        </PartnerContact>
        <PartnerContact>
          <ContactType>OR</ContactType>
          <Name>John Does wife</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>987654321</PhoneNumber>
          <EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
        </PartnerContact>
      </PartnerContacts>
  </Partner>
```

What I need:

```
  <Partner>
      <PartnerContacts>
          <ContactType>AR</ContactType>
          <Name>John Doe</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>0123456789</PhoneNumber>
          <EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
          <ContactType>OR</ContactType>
          <Name>John Does wife</Name>
          <PhoneNumber>987654321</PhoneNumber>
          <EmailAddress>test@test.com</EmailAddress>
      </PartnerContacts>
  </Partner>
```

I know that I can set an XmlElement attribute for the list property to remove the wrapper tag, but that's not what I need here.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: How would you know which nodes under `PartnerContacts` belong together in your desired format?

Comment: @PeterCsala Good question, but not realy my concern. This is how the external firm wants to receive the XML file..

Comment: Okay, could you please share with us how do you serialize your objects? (With which xml serializer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - XML serialization: omitting a certain element in my XML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927502/c-sharp-xml-serialization-omitting-a-certain-element-in-my-xml-output)

Comment: @PeterCsala This was not realy an option for me (as far as I could see) because I had other properties whithin my object (other than the partners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several things, including the use of `XmlElementAttribute` and `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`, but it did not give me the outcome I needed.

In the end I came up with the following solution:

My code:

```
public class Document
{
    public List<Partner> Partners { get; set; } = new List<Partner> { };
}

public class Partner
{

    public string PartnerType { get; set; }

    public PartnerContacts PartnerContacts { get; set; } = new PartnerContacts();
}

public class PartnerContacts
{
    [XmlElement("ContactType", Type = typeof(ContactType))]
    [XmlElement("Name", Type = typeof(Name))]
    [XmlElement("PhoneNumber", Type = typeof(PhoneNumber))]
    [XmlElement("EmailAddress", Type = typeof(EmailAddress))]
    public List<PartnerContact> PartnerContactsInfos { get; set; } = new List<PartnerContact>();

}

public abstract class PartnerContact
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ContactType : PartnerContact
{
}
public sealed class Name : PartnerContact
{
}
public sealed class PhoneNumber : PartnerContact
{
}
public sealed class EmailAddress : PartnerContact
{
}
```

This gets me the result I wanted:

```xml
<Document>
  <Partners>
    <Partner>
      <PartnerID>TestID</PartnerID>
      <PartnerContacts>
        <ContactType>AR</ContactType>
        <Name>John Doe</Name>
        <PhoneNumber>0123456789</PhoneNumber>
        <EmailAddress>test@tes.com</EmailAddress>
        <ContactType>OR</ContactType>
        <Name>John Does Wife</Name>
        <PhoneNumber>9876543210</PhoneNumber>
        <EmailAddress>test@tes.com</EmailAddress>
      </PartnerContacts>
    </Partner>
  </Partners>
</Document>
```