# XML attribute for ignoring class tag when serializating object c#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I need to get an xml output like this:

```
<Partners>
   <Partner>
      <PartnerType>SomeStringValue</PartnerType>
      <PartnerID>SomeStringValue</PartnerID>
      <PartnerIDType>SomeStringValue</PartnerIDType>
      <PartnerID>BTW BEXXXXXXXXXX</PartnerID>
      <PartnerIDType>SomeStringValue</PartnerIDType>
   </Partner>
   <Partner>
      <PartnerType>SomeStringValue</PartnerType>
      <PartnerID>SomeStringValue</PartnerID>
      <PartnerIDType>SomeStringValue</PartnerIDType>
      <PartnerID>BTW BEXXXXXXXXXX</PartnerID>
      <PartnerIDType>SomeStringValue</PartnerIDType>
   </Partner>
</Partners>
```

It has to be possible to add multiple PartnerID tags and multiple PartnerIDType tags in the parner tag. To get this result I was using a list of PartnerIdInfo. I had my classes like this:

```
public class Someclass
{
    public List<Partner> Partners {get; set;}
}

public class Partner
{
    public string PartnerType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("PartnerIdInfo")]
    public List<PartnerIdInfo> PartnerIDInfos { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerIdInfo
{
    public string PartnerID { get; set; }
    public string PartnerIDType { get; set; }
}
```

The [XmlElement("PartnerIdInfo")] tag is for not showing the  tag from the list property in the partner class. But it is still showing the tag :

```
<Partners>
   <Partner>
      <PartnerType>SomeStringValue</PartnerType>
      <PartnerIdInfo>
         <PartnerID>SomeStringValue</PartnerID>
         <PartnerIDType>SomeStringValue</PartnerIDType>
      </PartnerIdInfo>
      <PartnerIdInfo>
         <PartnerID>BTW BEXXXXXXXXXX</PartnerID>
         <PartnerIDType>SomeStringValue</PartnerIDType>
      </PartnerIdInfo>
   </Partner>
</Partners>
```

Is there an attibute (or another solution) to do this? I prefer not to rewrite my code and fill everything in the code through the use of XmlDocument and XmlNode... Or will this be the only possible solution for this outcome?

Comment: You are only getting one because it is not an array : public List<string> PartnerID { get; set; }

Comment: The problem is that you are combining the value of `PartnerType` with the values of the properties inside each item in the `List<PartnerIdInfo> PartnerIDInfos` inside a single element `<Partner>`.  You can't do that with your current data model.

Comment: One workaround would be to convert `PartnerIDInfos` to a list of choice values like the one from [Keep sort when deserialize and serialize XML using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130816/3744182).  Another option would be to use an `[XmlAnyElement]  public XElement[] Elements { }` array such as the one from [Xml Sequence deserialization with RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32885108).  Does either option meet your needs?

Comment: @dbc Yes the answer of the stringelementbase (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096673/keep-sort-when-deserialize-and-serialize-xml-using-xmlserializer/48130816#48130816) helped a lot!! Thank you! If you post your anser below, I will accept it.

Comment: @D.Brugmans - answer posted, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem** is that you want the serializer to combine the value of `Partner.PartnerType` with the repeating values of `Partner.PartnerIDInfos[*].PartnerID` and `Partner.PartnerIDInfos[*].PartnerIDType` into a single omnibus `<Partner>` element.  Unfortunately, this simply is not implemented.  The content of each `PartnerIdInfo` will always be serialized within its own element.

Several **workarounds** can be found in the answers to the questions *[Keep sort when deserialize and serialize XML using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48096673/3744182)* and *[Xml Deserialization - Merging two elements into a single List<T> object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37307203/3744182)*.  In particular using a polymorphic array of simple elements with two possible types corresponding to `<PartnerID>` and `<PartnerIDType>` should meet your needs.  You will need to modify `Partner` to mark the `PartnerIDInfos` as ignored and use a surrogate array for the elements:

```
public class Partner
{
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public string PartnerType { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<PartnerIdInfo> PartnerIDInfos { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(typeof(PartnerID), Order = 2), XmlElement(typeof(PartnerIDType), Order = 2)]
    public StringElementBase [] XmlPartnerIDInfos 
    {
        get => PartnerIDInfos?.SelectMany(p => new StringElementBase [] { new PartnerID { Value = p.PartnerID }, new PartnerIDType { Value = p.PartnerIDType } }).ToArray();
        set => PartnerIDInfos = value?.OfType<PartnerID>().Zip(value.OfType<PartnerIDType>(), (id, type) => new PartnerIdInfo { PartnerID = id.Value, PartnerIDType = type.Value }).ToList();
    }
}

public abstract class StringElementBase { [XmlText] public string Value { get; set; } } // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130816/3744182
public class PartnerID : StringElementBase { }
public class PartnerIDType : StringElementBase { }
```

Notes:

- Marking `StringElementBase.Value` with [`[XmlText]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute) causes the value to be serialized as text rather than nested markup.
- `StringElementBase [] XmlPartnerIDInfos` should be an array rather than a `List<StringElementBase>` because `XmlSerializer` will not set back the value of a resizable collection such as `List<T>` after populating it.
- Setting [XmlElement.Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order) is optional but does indicate that `<PartnerType>` not come between any of the `<PartnerID>` and `<PartnerIDType>` elements.
- In the setter for `XmlPartnerIDInfos` I don't attempt to validate that there are an equal number of `PartnerID` and `PartnerIDType` elements, or that the values alternate.  You could add that, if you wish.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0jguOj).